# Require an environment variable in docker compose

Tags: docker-compose, environment-variables

We have a docker compose file where an environment variable is required. It will fail in a very unclear way if not set, so I would like to proactively fail any `docker compose up` command if the variable is not there.

Is there a way to do so within docker compose, without putting a wrapper script around the command?

Comment: i think you won't get far without your wrapper script, i don't know any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce a new container to your compose file that validates the required variable is set. Make all your other services depend on it. For example:

```
services:
  envcheck:
    image: docker.io/alpine:latest
    command:
      - sh
      - -c
      - |
        if [ -z "$REQUIRED_VARIABLE" ]; then
          echo "ERROR: Missing REQUIRED_VARIABLE" >&2
          exit 1
        fi

  service1:
    image: docker.io/traefik/whoami
    depends_on:
      envcheck:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  service2:
    image: docker.io/traefik/whoami
    depends_on:
      envcheck:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
```

If `REQUIRED_VARIABLE` is not set, we see:

```
$ docker compose up
WARN[0000] The "REQUIRED_VARIABLE" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
[+] Running 3/1
 ✔ Container container-envcheck-1  Recreated                                                                                                                                            0.1s
 ✔ Container container-service1-1  Recreated                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 ✔ Container container-service2-1  Recreated                                                                                                                                            0.0s
Attaching to envcheck-1, service1-1, service2-1
envcheck-1  | ERROR: Missing REQUIRED_VARIABLE
envcheck-1 exited with code 1
service "envcheck" didn't complete successfully: exit 1
```

But if we set it first, we see:

```
$ REQUIRED_VARIABLE=test docker compose up
[+] Running 3/3
 ✔ Container container-envcheck-1  Recreated                                                                                                                                            0.1s
 ✔ Container container-service2-1  Recreated                                                                                                                                           10.4s
 ✔ Container container-service1-1  Recreated                                                                                                                                           10.2s
Attaching to envcheck-1, service1-1, service2-1
envcheck-1 exited with code 0
service1-1  | 2024/01/29 21:03:36 Starting up on port 80
service2-1  | 2024/01/29 21:03:36 Starting up on port 80
```